# mdadm raid drive missing after restart; parititions no longer show in fdisk/gparted

Tags: linux, ubuntu, software-raid, mdadm

I'm in the process of creating a RAID 1 array with two 2TB disks. I was following the [instructions for mdadm on the kernel wiki](https://raid.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/A_guide_to_mdadm#Assembling_your_arrays) and successfully started the RAID process.

```
sudo mdadm --create /dev/md/raid1 /dev/sda1 /dev/sdb1 --level=1 --raid-devices=2
```

(note the partition numbers)

I got carried away and restarted the computer before the sync completed. When I rebooted, I saw that the partitions were gone.

`/etc/mdadm/mdadm.conf` didn't show any information about the RAID and gparted and fdisk both show the disk as physically fine but with no partitions.

I found several different articles, most of them saying to try `--assemble` but I kept getting errors of a bad superblock.  Then I went down a rabbit hole of partition superblocks and found [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/484532/429161):

> recreate the RAID with e.g. mdadm --create /dev/md0 --level=1 --raid-devices=2 /dev/sdc /dev/sda

I tried this command, noting the lack of partition numbers, and it still didn't work. I'm hoping that my data is still intact and can be recovered. I'm tempted to recreate the partition table but not sure if that would even work.

My question: how can I recover the RAID?  If I can't recover the RAID, can I recover the data?

Thanks!